# How to avoid cyclical references in EF4.4 design using attributes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have three tables: **PropertyOwner**, **Property** and **Address**.

A **PropertyOwner** has lots of **Properties**.

A **PropertyOwner** has an **Address**.

Each **Property** also has an **Address**.

Here is the code first for Entity Framework 4.4:

```
Table: PropertyOwner

[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[Required]
public Guid PropertyOwnerId { get; set; }

[Required]
[ForeignKey("Address")]
public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
public virtual Address Address { get; set; }


Table: Property

[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[Required]
public Guid PropertyId { get; set; }

[Required]
[ForeignKey("PropertyOwner")]
public Guid PropertyOwnerId { get; set; }
public virtual PropertyOwner PropertyOwner { get; set; }

[Required]
[ForeignKey("Address")]
public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
public virtual Address Address { get; set; }


Table: Address

[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[Required]
public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(64)]
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
```

When I try to create this database, I get the following error:

```
The referential relationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed. [ Constraint name = FK_dbo.PropertyOwner_dbo.Address_AddressId ]
```

Does the database think that the **Property**'s **Address** and the **PropertyOwner**'s **Address** are the same record?

How can I spell it out in the attributes that the **Property** needs to have it's own address and the **PropertyOwner** also needs to have its own **Address**?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you don't need to explicitly specify foreign keys in classes `Property` and `PropertyOwner`. Proper keys will be generated in the DB by EF, based only on `public virtual Address Address` property. Try that and see if that gets rid of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I removed all mention of foreign keys and it makes no difference.

Comment: This guy had a similar situation, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367339/net-mvc-cyclical-reference-issue-with-entity